# Pre-create a facebook post in html and submit

Tags: facebook, posting

Problem:
I have a list of "products" from my customer with various text/images. On a webpage. I would like to be able to make a function for them to MANUALLY push a button and have a facebook post CREATED for them, but NOT send automatically.

Reason: They want to control and edit it before posting, but save time in creating and getting the facts automatically inserted. They will just post as the currently logged in user.

I have attached an example screenshot of what I would like my customer to see after pressing a button.

I have tried: All kinds of things with a sharebutton. Alas, theres no page to share....and limited things to do with content.. I am unsure if I need to create an app, or if it can be solved by posting the info somewhere

What to do?

[image: Pre-created but not sent]

Comment: The text is plain text, and images just added as standard facebook posts work. No formatting needed

Comment: About the images are they locally available or through URLs to locations on the internet? (Are they on your computer or they are online?)

Comment: Also can you provide an example of how the webpage containing the products list looks like? (a screenshot or actual html page)

Comment: @IbrahimShendy thanks for taking time...... I control the product list completely, and can construct whatever needed. It will not be public in terms of searchable, have links to it, or meant to be shared, but wil be assecible for whomever holds the link, mainly the facebook editor of the company. Images are available via url. I also have server access, and could do .NET-development for whatever is nessecary ...

Comment: A bit more background: The products are infact apartments for rent - mainly in -errmm - less desirable areas.... they do not want to publicly show there are say 10 vacant apartments at a time, marking it as a bad neighborhood, thus no public lists. Buts its not secrets. The images and textx that goes with each apartment from the database may not be up to date, therefor the post needs to be editable before doing the actual posting, altering/adding text, replacing an image or whatever.

Comment: Do you want to post on a user timeline or on a page feed (which is supported by Facebook apps unlike on a user timeline)?

Comment: I dont want to post for them. Just to pre-create suggested content of a post from the data I have from their database. What edits they will make, where they post and when they do it is up to them.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you create a page that generates the content that the customers will be using, and allow the users to **copy and paste** that content directly to their facebook account (either to post it on their timeline or somewhere else - like a page or a group - they will decide).

You can also help them with a **guide** on how to do that, by providing a list of steps they should **follow** to copy and paste the content.

For uploading the **images**, as they are provided as **URLs**, you can guide them on how to use those URLs directly to upload the images on facebook. And that is how:

> Select **Add Photo/Video**. Click
>   on **Upload Photo/Video**.
>
> Click **Choose File** and in the dialog box that appears,
>
> Paste the **URL** of
>   the image you want to share on Facebook in the field next to **"File name"**
>
> Click **Open**. It will
>   automatically upload the image to Facebook.

Comment: heh, yeah...... This is a solution, though I was hoping to avoid all the copy/pasting by the user. They can make quite a few posts this way in the time it takes me to figure out a more elegant solution.

Comment: I hope you find better results here in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through in Facebook Page Composer via an unpublished Page post that isn't immediately published on your Page or in your News Feed.

Unpublished Page posts allow Page admins to manage the delivery of advertising content using audience filters. These scheduled or draft posts are delivered on future publication date or through promotion within an ad set.

Once your customer is happy with it, he/she can publish or schedule it.

See more details on this link: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/357923380922077?helpref=faq_content

Comment: This is manual construction. I need to create the contents for them from misc data I have. And they themselves decide if and when